# What do classes in non leaves of Decision Tree represent?

Tags: machine-learning

I am unable to understand what does class = setosa in depth 0 mean? In general, do nonleaf classes have any significance?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the majority of the units in that node are of class setosa, so if you were to make a prediction at that point it would be that the class is setosa.